# Unexpected behavior when using screen with init.d

Tags: linux, ubuntu, java

I added a shell script in startup with the following command:

```
su - root -c "/usr/bin/screen -dmS SomeServer java -jar /home/SomeServer.jar"
```

When I normally run this command, `screen` is created & works. But when I use `screen -ls` after reboot I see nothing.

Interesting thing is `SomeServer.jar` has http server built in, when I use `netstat` I can see a Java process listening on this port.

I am using Ubuntu 14.04.

Answer (score 0):

I cannot see how the above command could possibly be working on Ubuntu: *su*'ing to root will prompt you for root's password. Good luck finding that, in Ubuntu.

The above command should be instead:

```
 sudo /usr/bin/screen -dmS SomeServer java -jar /home/SomeServer.jar
```

without quotes. I also have to ask you: if you have created a startup script to do this, why do you need to execute the above command as root? It will be executed as such automatically, even if you include the line above, without the *sudo* qualifier, inside */etc/rc.local*, a quick and dirty way to start this at boot.

I cannot test the above command, so I am relying on you to tell me whether more fixing is needed.

Comment: It is a server & doesnot have ant root password. It has a root account. Still running your solution gives produces same output

Answer (score 0):

Assuming "reboot" was not a mis-type in your post, your problem is that screens do not persist across reboot cycles.

If that was a mistake and you have not actually rebooted, then it is likely you are not running `screen -ls` as root -- screen will only show you active screen sessions for your current user. Use `sudo su -` to switch to root and then try again.

Comment: I tried using all users.Even listed all active screen using `ls -laR /var/run/screen/` but found no active screen

Comment: Are you or are you not rebooting the host in this scenario?

Comment: I am rebooting.

Comment: That's your problem. Screens do not persist across reboots.

Comment: I cannot understand the issue. When i add same command in init.d.There is no screen running. But command keeps on running in background. But when i run same command normally i get screen in list.

Comment: I really think you need to clarify your question. If you are running this script on reboot via the init system, then that is a different scenario. Please add more details.

Comment: I missed reboot :D